# Helm Charts: specify values files for subcharts in umbrella chart file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have several charts that I would like to deploy together.

Chart.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: solution-chart
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0

appVersion: 1.16.0

dependencies:
- name: ingress-nginx
  version: 2.13.0
  repository: "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"  
- name: service1
  version: 0.1.0
- name: service2
  version: 0.1.0
- name: service3
  version: 0.1.0
```

Service1, Service2 and Service3 have different values file, one for local-config and one for production-config.

Is it possible to somehow specify the values file in the dependency section of the Chart.yaml file?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit what you want to achieve?
You want to deploy in 1 cluster all charts with for example local-vaule.yaml and after a while prod-values.yaml and be able to switch between them?

Comment: I would like to do something like adding a third field after the version "values: service1/chart/values.local.yaml"

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you use `helmfile` for resolving the following issue.

I'm using it and usually wrapping all charts and their dependencies like this:

```
releases:
    - name: service1
      chart: ./charts/service1
      values:
          - ./values/service1.yaml
    - name: service2
      chart: ./charts/service2
      values:
          - ./values/service2.yaml
    - name: service3
      chart: ./charts/service3
      values:
          - ./values/service3.yaml
```

Try to reach the documentation and find is it acceptable for your case:

https://github.com/roboll/helmfile